# File upload with php issue moving file

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I can't upload a file in my server using php. The problem is that I can't find see which is the error, or I don't know how see it. By the way, I think is something about the file moving. This is the php code

```
<!-- upload -->
    <?php
        if (isset($_FILES["myFile"])) {
            $myFile = $_FILES["myFile"];
            // File prop
            $myFileName = $myFile["name"];
            $myFileTmp = $myFile["tmp_name"];
            $myFileSize = $myFile["size"];
            $myFileError = $myFile["error"];

            //File extension
            $myFileExt = explode(".", $myFileName);
            $myFileExt = strtolower(end($myFileExt));
            $allowed = array ('png' , 'jpg' , 'txt');

            if(in_array($myFileExt, $allowed)) {
                if($myFileError === 0) {
                    $newFileName = uniqid('', true) . '.' .$myFileExt;
                    $fileDestination = "/var/www/upload".$newFileName;

                    if(move_uploaded_file($myFileTmp, $fileDestination)) {
                        print_r($fileDestination);
                    } else {
                        print_r($myFileError);
                    }
                } else {
                  print_r("error");
                }
            } else {
              print_r("error");
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin:15px"> 
             <input type="file" style="margin:5px" name="myFile">
             <input type="submit" class="btn-upload-file" style="margin:5px" value="Upload">
            </form>
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you're using ubuntu/apache, check the contents at the bottom of /var/log/apache2/error.log - might give you some indicator as to which part is failing.

Comment: Does the action in the form point to the file?

Comment: The action should be point at the same file..php and html parts are in the same index.php file.. I'm new with php, have i to declare the file even if it's that one and not another?

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that it fails here move_uploaded_file

Comment: Your code is OK except that you forgot to add a Directory Separator ("/") between upload and $newFileName...  it should be like so: **"/var/www/upload/" . $newFileName;**

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is very Minor... 
You just missed a **Slash(/)** after the /www/uploads.
Try this:

```
<?php
        if (isset($_FILES["myFile"])) {
            $myFile         = $_FILES["myFile"];
            // File prop
            $myFileName     = $myFile["name"];
            $myFileTmp      = $myFile["tmp_name"];
            $myFileSize     = $myFile["size"];
            $myFileError    = $myFile["error"];

            //File extension
            $myFileExt = explode(".", $myFileName);
            $myFileExt = strtolower(end($myFileExt));
            $allowed = array ('png' , 'jpg' , 'txt');

            if(in_array($myFileExt, $allowed)) {
                if($myFileError === 0) {
                    $newFileName        = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $myFileExt;
                    $fileDestination    = "/var/www/upload/{$newFileName}";        //YOU WERE ONLY MISSING A SLASH (/) HERE AFTER /upload
                    if(move_uploaded_file($myFileTmp, $fileDestination)) {
                        print_r($fileDestination);
                    } else {
                        print_r($myFileError);
                    }
                } else {
                    print_r("error");
                }
            } else {
                print_r("error");
            }
        }
    ?>


    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin:15px">
        <input type="file" style="margin:5px" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" class="btn-upload-file" style="margin:5px" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

Comment: Hmm i don't know if this is the error because i've got the same issue. It fails here: if(move_uploaded_file($myFileTmp, $fileDestination)) and the print_r($myFileError); returns "0".